# Delete/Exclude records from table, if it exists in another table, even if some fields are blank

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create either a table or a query that contains all the records from Table1, but deletes or excludes all the records that also exist in Table2.

I have tried creating a delete query that creates a new table with the records excludes, and a select query that shows all but the excluded records.

I have been comparing these two tables based on 16 fields. It's very possible that two records in Table1 will be the same except for one field, and it may not always be the same field. That's why I can't compare the two tables based on one field each time.

This all works fine, providing each of the 16 fields are not blank. It is possible for some fields to be empty, but when I run the query, only the records with none of the fields I'm comparing being blank are deleted/excluded, any others still remain. I've tried running the query without comparing the fields that may contain blanks, but then it excludes more records due to duplicate information in the remaining fields.

How can I exclude the matching records, with it comparing empty fields accurately? I don't mind if its a delete or select query, and I don't mind using SQL. What's also important is that the fields in Table1 and Table2 are not changed in any way. I can only delete the necessary data in Table1, not change it.

I am using Microsoft Access 2010.

EDIT: Here's an example image (these aren't the exact tables I'm using, but examples I quickly created for this question):
[IMAGE: Duplicates not deleted accurately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PECe5.png)

The first table is Table1, which shows all the records. The records outlined in red have Duplicate Business Event IDs, so one must be excluded. For the first pair of duplicates (ID 4), I will exclude the second record, as the Nett and Final Price is lower. For the second pair (ID 6) I will remove the second record as the customer retracted their cancellation and then renewed. For the third pair (ID 10), I will exclude the first record as the Nett and Final Price are lower, and the Scheme is blank.

The second table contains exact copies of the three records I wish to exclude. These are, and will always be, manually entered. Not that ID 6 and ID 10 have blank fields.

The third image shows the SQL code I wrote that will delete a record in Table1 if all the fields matches all the corresponding fields in Table2.

The final image shows the Datasheet View of the query, and the records that will be deleted when I Run the Delete query. Only the record with ID 4 will be deleted, as it is the only record with no blank fields.

Comment: Can you show a small sample of what you are trying to do here exactly?

Comment: I've included an image with an example of what happens. These are tables I very quickly whipped up in the past hour so aren't the same as the tables I am working on. But the process and the problem is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it for hours, I have managed to find a solution myself.

[IMAGE of SQL Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M1yi.png)

I added an extra condition for each field that tested if both fields in each Table were empty (Null) as well as being equal. After doing this, the Delete query deleted all the necessary fields required.